# Raw multiline string in bash?

Tags: bash, python

Is there a way to get an uninterpreted string in bash - it could include single and ouble quotes and Bang ! etc. ?

I want to do something like

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -e "Line One\nLine Two\nLine three" | python -c """
import sys
for line in sys.stdin.readlines():
  print "STDIN: %s" %line
""" | awk '{print $2}'
```

Problem is that zero STDIN: lines are printed - stdin is not being piped to the python program.

Here is a usecase: note the input size can be low GB's size:

cat "my10GBfile.dat" | python -c """  .. etc

Now using a HEREDOC in there .e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -e "Line One\nLine Two\nLine three" | python<<-HERE
some

multiline
python 
program
HERE
| awk '{print $2}'
```

has problem that the stdin gets coopted - and thus the input is lost.

What I really want is that uninterpreted multiline string in bash.

Comment: Could you give an example closer to what you actually want to do, i.e. a less theoretical and a more practical one? I find that as of now there is some ambiguity in what you are trying to accomplish (you say that STDIN is lost, but you don't show how it is supposed to be used — there might be a workaround for specific tasks).

Comment: @Daniel  i added the print statement inside python, and explanation they do not print anything.

Comment: Note that the natural way would be to access the file directly from within Python. You can most likely do everything you can do with AWK and other CLI tools directly within native Python, with possibly substantial speedups. The shell is powerful, but when more complete scripting languages have already been thrown in the mix (typically Perl/Python) there is even more power to be harnessed. Another possibility if the Python functions are simple is to expand AWK to perform their part in the script and pass the filename directly to AWK. Using `cat` in this way is seldom the "right" way to go.

Comment: @Daniel. don't disagree in principle. I have python scripts in the hundreds to low K's of lines. Sometimes already have things coded in shell-ish stuff and don't want to perturb them, just insert a single step and this makes python an option in that case as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The heredoc *does* provide an uninterpreted multiline string (at least if you quote the delimiter); there's just no (easy) way of accessing its content.

Since STDIN is already being used for something else, you can create a new file descriptor to pass the heredoc's content to python:

```
exec 3<<'HERE'
import sys
print "Line Zero!\n"
for line in sys.stdin:
    print line
HERE
echo -e "Line One\nLine Two\nLine Three" | python /dev/fd/3
```

Comment: This may well be what I am looking for: I had been considering pipes but file descriptor is instead transparent to the script itself. I will try it out!

Comment: works great. thx

Answer (score 2):

No need to get fancy in any way: just single quote the multiline string:

```
echo -e "Line One\nLine Two\nLine three" | python -c '
  import sys
  for line in sys.stdin.readlines():
    print "STDIN: %s" %line
' | awk '{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 0):

How about (using the `< <()` Bash construct to emulate line-by-line input):

```
$ while read i; do echo -e '
#this is a multiline python program
if True:
    print """line: '"$i"'"""
' | python | awk '{print $0, "→", $3}'; done < <(echo -e "Line One\nLine Two\nLine Three")
```

which gives output:

```
line: Line One → One
line: Line Two → Two
line: Line Three → Three
```

Using Python's internal `"""` syntax, the strings will be protected from everything except three quotes. Using `read` in this fashion will invoke the Python program once for every line. This works in the example you've given, but your actual task might be different (which is why I asked for a specific example in the comments). Perhaps the quoting "trick" might be of use anyway.

If Python is to be used at all, it seems easier to just do all the manipulation from within the Python code; it is after all a competent scripting language.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  My usecase involves linecounts in the hundreds up to low millions, so restarting python each line would not be optimal.  The input will be a cat'ed file of size low GB's.

Comment: I added the use case above.